# Prove that inequality $2- \frac{\pi^2}{6} \le \log(\sqrt{2\pi})$ holds

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to prove that the following inequality holds:

$$2- \frac{\pi^2}{6} \le \log(\sqrt{2\pi})$$

Can you give me a hint for this?

Comment: Bad title...  You have a tag "inequality" so people already know that you are asking about an inequality.  Your title can basically be the title of all inequality questions here.  This is not the first time you asked questions.  Please be more descriptive.

Comment: You're right. I will definitely improve on this.

Comment: Looking $\log(\sqrt{2\pi})$ it might be related to stirling's approximation? Or gamma function?

Comment: Does "log" mean the natural logarithm or log base $10$?

Answer (score 2):

$\log(\sqrt{2\pi}) \approx 0.399 > 0.36$

$2-\frac{\pi^2}{6} \approx 0.355 < 0.36$

Thus, $2-\frac{\pi^2}{6} < 0.36 < \log(\sqrt{2\pi})$ as desired.

Comment: Since the OP never specifies what is allowed in the proof, this is as good an answer this question deserves.  And it is a perfectly valid proof.  Not sure why it is being downvoted.

Comment: You're using log base $10$ rather than the natural logarithm, right?

Comment: Yes indeed, correct. $\ln = \frac{\log_{10}}{\log_{10}e} > \log_{10}$, so if you want natural logarithm, it's even larger. @BarryCipra

Comment: @GarethMa, it'll be interesting to see which log the OP intended. Base $10$ certainly makes for a smaller difference.

Answer (score 0):

Making the problem more general, consider the function $$f(x)=2- \frac{x^2}{6} - \log(\sqrt{2x})$$ Since $x>0$, let $x=\sqrt t$ and, after expanding, consider the function
$$g(t)=-\frac{t}{6}-\frac{\log (t)}{4}+2-\frac{\log (2)}{2}$$ Its derivative is always negative; so $g(t)$ is a decreasing function.

Now, its zero is given by
$$t=\frac{3}{2} W\left(\frac{e^8}{6}\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). If you do not know the value of $t$ use the series expansion for large $u$ (it is given in the linked page)
$$W(u)\approx L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\frac{L_2(2L_2^2-9L_2+6)}{6L_1^3}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(u)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$.

This formula would give $W\left(\frac{e^8}{6}\right)\approx 4.66756 $ while its exact value is $4.66760$. So $t=7.00133$ and then $x=2.64600$

So, for any $x > 2.64600$, $f(x) <0$. Since in your case, $x=\pi$.

Comment: Are you assuming "log" means the *natural* logarithm?

Comment: @BarryCipra. Sorry for that but I only know one logarithm ! Yes, $\log(.)=\ln(.)$ for me. Cheers :-)

Comment: It's interesting the inequality is still true with a base $10$ log (as Gareth Ma's answer shows).

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$2-{\pi^2\over6}\lt\log{\sqrt{2\pi}}\iff 4-{\pi^2\over3}\lt\log2\pi$$

Now if "log" means the natural logarithm, the inequality follows easily: $\pi\gt3\gt e$ implies

$$4-{\pi^2\over3}\lt4-{3^2\over3}=1=\log e\lt\log\pi\lt\log2\pi$$

If "log" means log base $10$, the inequality is still true, but will be harder to prove; I can't think of anything better than Gareth Ma's computational confirmation.

Comment: With $\log_{10}$, the solution is $x=3.10194$ ! Amazing